# How to load an array with different sizes into the html (google spreadsheet script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a newbie and figure out the possibilities of google spreadsheet scripts. I try to read out the column titles of my spreadsheat and to load it into the html side of the google script. I'm able to read out a whole array but I can't figure out how to read out each single range (e.q. B1, C1, D1,...) of a table. The next problem i have is, that I don't know beforehand the number of columns that I have to bring into the html.

Who can help me?

------ code.gs -------

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ProbeGUI')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');

}


function WriteToSpreadsheet(input) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1PkakB0cZKtzSxJUFULZjJBEPb-7U6XOASI69yOopWRM"); //Der Sheetname lautet ProbeCode
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Datenpool");
  var firstEmptyRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange("B"+(firstEmptyRow)); //In " " steht, in welche Spalte geschrieben wird

  range.setValue(input);
}


function WriteToFormular() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1PkakB0cZKtzSxJUFULZjJBEPb-7U6XOASI69yOopWRM");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Datenpool");
  var LastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
//  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, LastColumn);
  var values = range.getValues();

//  return values[0][ColumnCount];    
//  Browser.msgBox(values);
  return values;
}
```

---- html code ----

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function SendData() {
           google.script.run.WriteToSpreadsheet(document.Formular.IdeenWert.value);
        }

        function ReadSpreadsheet() {
             alert("ReadSpreadsheet");
//           google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(add_Item_row).WriteToFormular();
           google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ChooseItem).WriteToFormular();
        }

        function add_Item_row(ItemNamen) {
           var parent = document.getElementById('newDiv');
           var child = document.createElement('p');
//           var NewItem = ItemNamen[0][1];

           child.innerHTML = ItemNamen;
           parent.appendChild(child);
}


        function ChooseItem(SpreadsheetSpaltenNamen){
             alert(SpreadsheetSpaltenNamen);
var i = 0;
             alert(i);
             while (SpreadsheetSpaltenNamen[0][i] != "") {
                function add_Item_row(SpreadsheetSpaltenNamen[0][i])
                i++;
             }
          }




function validate_num(formdata) {
  formdata.value=formdata.value.replace(/\D/, '' );
}


    </script>

<body onload="ReadSpreadsheet();">
    <form name="Formular" action="" >
       <div style="position:relative; width:100px; top:20px; " >Restbetrag:</div><div style="position:relative; left:100px; width:100px; height:30px;" id="RestGeld">100</div>

       <div style="float:left; width:100px;" id="Item">Item</div><div><input id="WerteID" name="IdeenWert" type="text" size="7" onkeyup="validate_num(this)" onblur="formSubmit(this.value)" /></div>
       <div style="clear:both"></div> 


       <div style="position:relative; top:20px; left:100px; " ><input onclick="SendData();" type="button" value="OK" /></div> <!-- google.script.host.close() -->
   </form>


<div id='vendordiv'>
      <p>
      <input type="Button" value="Spreadsheet auslesen"     onclick="ReadSpreadsheet()"/>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id ='newDiv'>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Looping Array Elements - Sounds like you want to understand JavaScript arrays - lots of tutorials on that. See Looping Array Elements at: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp the section:

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got some errors in the client side.  so i made a change just to test the button "Spreadsheet auslesen"

```
onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ChooseItem).WriteToFormular();"
```

I was not able to find the reason of why making the call on the way you are doing it does not work, i will update the answer when i find it.

also in the function "ChooseItem" inside the while loop, you have "function", delete it so you can call the function instead of trying to create a new one.

after those modification i was able to insert the titles in the html.
hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, I found my problem and fixed it.